# Calculate transcendence degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,t]/(xz-y^{2},yt-z^{2},xt-yz)$ (i have proved in a previous question that is an integral domain).

I am trying to calculate the transcendence degree of $Frac(R)$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

This what i tried:

Consider the extensions $\mathbb{C} \subset Frac(R) \subset C(u,v)$ , since $trdeg_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}(u,v)=2<\infty$ , we know that $trdeg_{\mathbb{C}}C(u,v)=trdeg_{\mathbb{C}}Frac(R)+trdeg_{Frac(R)}\mathbb{C}(u,v)$.

Do you have any idea about proving $trdeg_{Frac(R)}\mathbb{C}(u,v)=0$? It seems rather difficult to compute $Frac(R)$ and dont really see any other way to show the result.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to use the map $f(x,y,z,t) \rightarrow  f(u^3,u^2v,uv^2,v^3)$ and 1st theorem of isomorphism.

Comment: @RHspqr First of all thanks! Doing as you told me i obtain an isomorphism between $R$ and $im(\phi)$ but how can i conclude that $trdeg_{Frac(R)}(\mathbb{C}[u,v])=0$?

Comment: Now the image is a subring of $\mathbb{C}[u,v]$, try to show $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ is algebraic over its fraction field , notice that algebraic extensions has transcendence degree 0.

Comment: @RHspqr I am really sorry but i really dont see how to show that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ is algebraic over $Frac(im(\phi))$. Do i have to compute the minimal polynomials of u,v over $Frac(im(\phi))$? The thing i am struggling with visualizing $Frac(im(\phi))$

Comment: In fact $im(\phi) = \mathbb{C}[u^3,u^2v,uv^2,v^3]$, so you could find some polynomials (not necessarily minimal) whose roots are $u,v$ respectively. For instance, try $x^3-u^3 \in im(\phi)[x]$